# Can I have more than one success (onepage) page in magento

Tags: magento

Can I have more than one success (onepage) page in magento. One for Cash on delivery and another for Online Bank transfer.

thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the template file for checkout success page (checkout/success.phtml) to display what you want it to for each method used. You have access to the order object in the template and can do everything there. If you need additional functionality just extend the checkout success block and use the new functions in the template. Absolutely no need to create a new success page and if you did you would need to extend the checkout controller which could cause you problems down the line with upgrades etc.

```
<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId()); ?>

<?php if ($order->getPayment()->getMethod() == "checkmo"): ?>
    <p>Check or Money Order HTML</p>
<?php else if ($order->getPayment()->getMethod() == "bank_transfer"): ?>
    <p>Bank Transfer HTML</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

See this article by fontis for more information: http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/customise-magento-checkout-success-page-based-payment-type

Comment: Dear thanks for reply,but my question is can i make two success page ............

Comment: Dear Ashley I am a developer and i did it using this but client say that no please make two different pages , thats why i asking this question.

Comment: If you must have two pages, then create a new phtml file and then a block in layout xml file. Then extend the checkouts onepage controller and override the place order function to do the detection and redirect to appropriate page.